# Editext setError icon disappear on Android 4.4.2 and 4.3 when length of my edittext is 0 and I press delete one more time

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm using the setError on my Edittext.
It's working when I need to show the message but on Android 4.4.2 and 4.3 when my Edittext has length = 0 and I press delete one more time, the icon and message error gone.

On Android 6.0 and 6.0.1 this isn't happenning.

Here is my code

```
private void enableBtnSend() {
    if (isDatesSelected() && etDetails.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
        btnCreateEnalbled = true;
        etDetails.setError(null);
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    } else {
        if(etDetails.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
            etDetails.setError(getString(R.string.empty_description_field));
        } else {
            etDetails.setError(null);
        }
        btnCreateEnalbled = false;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
}

private TextWatcher onEtAnswerChanged() {
    return new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            Log.i("beforeTextChanged","beforeTextChanged");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            Log.i("onTextChanged","onTextChanged");
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            enableBtnSend();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void enableBtnSend() {
    if (isDatesSelected() && etDetails.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
        btnCreateEnalbled = true;
        etDetails.setError(null);
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    } else {
        if(etDetails.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {


        etDetails.setError(getString(R.string.empty_description_field));
    etDetails.requestFocus(); //add this
            } else {
                etDetails.setError(null);
    etDetails.requestFocus(); //add this
            }
            btnCreateEnalbled = false;
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    }
```

It will work.